# Parse complex JSON object with GSON with changing content due to OOP

Tags: java, android, oop, interface, parent-child

I get such a JSON from the server and want to parse it to my objects:

```
"product":{
"product_type":"assignment",
"id":717,
    "product_profile":{
    "title":"new Order from java",
    "info":"Some special info",
    "dtl_expl":true,
    "special_info":""
    }
}
```

Depend on "product_type" value I get different value of "product_profile" from server. The "product_profile" can be one of three types. I created class presentation for each of them. But question is that how organize correct parsing of JSON object to my Product class due to OOP principles? Should I create interface and implement it in each of my three classes, or I should create one parent class and extend it in my three classes to make it work right?

My classes structure. First of all Product class , object of which I should get as a result from json:

```
 public class Product {
    ProductAssignment prodAss;
    ProductWriting prodWr;
    ProductType returnState;

    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;
    @SerializedName("product_type")
    String product_type;
    @SerializedName("product_profile")
    ProductType product_profile;

    public Product()
    {}
    public Product(int id, String product_type, ProductType product_profile)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.product_type = product_type;
        this.product_profile = product_profile.returnObject(product_type);
    }

    public int getProductId() 
    {

         return this.id;
    }
    public String getProductType() 
    {
         return this.product_type;
    }
    public ProductType getProduct() 
    {
         return product_profile.returnObject(product_type);
    }
    public void setProductId(int id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setProductTitle(String product_type) 
    {
        this.product_type = product_type;
    }
    public void setProduct(ProductType product_profile) 
    {
        this.product_profile = product_profile;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id=" + id + " " + "title=" + product_type
                + " " + "profile=" + product_profile  +  "}";
    }

}
```

Now parent class ProductType for two subclasses:

```
    public class ProductType extends ProductType{
    String product;

    static ProductType productType;
    static ProductAssignment productAssignment;
    static ProductWriting productWriting;
    IProductType component;

    private ProductType returnState;
    ProductAssignment prodAss;
    ProductWriting prodWr;
    public ProductType()
    {       
    }
    public ProductType(IProductType c)
    {
         component = c;
    }
   // implemented method of interface
    @Override
    public ProductType returnObject(String product_type) 
    {
        System.out.println("ProductType");
        if (product_type.equals("assignment"))
            returnState =  prodAss.returnObject(product_type);
        else if  (product_type.equals("writing"))
            returnState =  prodWr.returnObject(product_type);
        System.out.println(returnState.getClass().getName());
        return returnState;
    }
}
```

One of the subclasses:

```
public class ProductWriting extends ProductType{

    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    String title;
    @SerializedName("pages_number")
    int pages_number;
    @SerializedName("number_of_references")
    String number_of_references;
    @SerializedName("dtl_expl")
    boolean dtl_expl;
    @SerializedName("info")
    String info;



public ProductWriting()
        {}
        public ProductWriting(String title, String info, boolean dtl_expl, 
                int pages_number ,
                int id,String number_of_references)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.info = info ;
            this.dtl_expl = dtl_expl;
            this.id = id;
            this.pages_number = pages_number;
            this.number_of_references = number_of_references;

        }
        public ProductWriting(IProductType c){
            super(c);
        }
        // getters and setters

         @Override
         public ProductType returnObject(String res) {
             System.out.println("Writing");    
               super.returnObject(res);
                 return new ProductWriting();
         }

}
```

Another one :

```
public class ProductAssignment extends ProductType{
ProductAssignment thisObj;
@SerializedName("title")
String title;
@SerializedName("info")
String info;
@SerializedName("dtl_expl")
boolean dtl_expl;
@SerializedName("special_info")
String special_info;
@SerializedName("shoot_exclusive_video")
boolean shoot_exclusive_video;
@SerializedName("shoot_common_video")
boolean shoot_common_video;
public ProductAssignment()
{}
public ProductAssignment(String title, String info, boolean dtl_expl, String special_info,
        boolean shoot_common_video, boolean shoot_exclusive_video)
{

    this.title = title;
    this.info = info ;
    this.dtl_expl = dtl_expl;
    this.special_info = special_info;
    this.shoot_common_video = shoot_common_video;
    this.shoot_exclusive_video =shoot_exclusive_video;
}
// getters and setters

 @Override
 public  ProductType returnObject(String res) {
     System.out.println("Assignment");
     super.returnObject(res);
         return new ProductAssignment();
 }
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "title=" + title + "info " + "=" + info
            + " " + "profile=" + dtl_expl +  "}";
}
```

}

Interface for binding my classes:

```
    public interface IProductType 
{
     ProductType returnObject(String parse);
}
```

I tried to implement in this way, but it doesn't work for now with it.

Comment: How are the 3 different product_types different?

Comment: it can contain either Assignmnent, Essay or Question object.

Comment: Can you post an example of each?